# How to name HTML elements in User Controls?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I recently designed my own user control.

My control consists of an ASP:Tree control and a plain HTML text input with copious Javascript, jQuery, and .net code to bring them to life together.

I have two issues.

1) I can only have one instance of this control on a page at a time.  The text input is named txtUserControl, so putting a second instance on the page causes a name collision.  I have the same issue with the ASP:Tree.

2) If I put my user control inside an ASP:UpdatePanel, it does not work at all.  I get errors all over the page when I try to refresh it.  Incidently, I have this same issue with a user control created by one of my co-workers.

I have some ideas for controls that I would like to be able to use again and again in my projects.  I would like them to be rock-solid.

What are the best practices for sorting these issues out?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `runat="server"` on your `HTML` controls, they will be auto-assigned a unique ID across instances of user controls.  You would need to reference your control using the `ClientID` property on the server-side, like this:

```
// javascript code
function doStuff() {
    var myUserControl = $get('<% =MyUserControl.ClientID %>');
};
```

Comment: This is a little bit different from what I asked.  I did say that I used an ASP:Tree control.  However, I also used a plain html text input, not an ASP:Textbox control.  Would it be easier to work with in my user control if I used an ASP:TextBox instead of a plain html text input?

Comment: You can put `runat="server"` on your plain html text input.  Like this: `<input id="input123" runat="server" />`, which is what I was meaning.  It turns it into an `HtmlControl` running on the server side, which is like a `WebControl`, only it is the straight `HTML` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your issues will be eliminated if you convert your User Control into a [Composite Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479016.aspx).

Sometimes getting it to work the first time is a little tricky, however, it is worth the investment of time to learn how to create these and use them.